# How to modify a record with a Specific ListID in Quickbooks Using c#

Tags: c#, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, qbxml, qbfc

I am new to QuickBooks development.

I have successfully managed to call add records and query but I am having problems figuring out how to modify records.

I have quick books ListIds stored in a separate system, I would like modify the specific record in Quickbooks using the list ID as a defining criteria.

I am using c#.

I have a QSessionManager and IMsgSetDefined defined.

So to preform a modification on say vendor I would imaging that I would proceed as follows:

```
QBSessionManager sessionManager = new SessionManager();
sessionManager.OpenConnection("MyAPP", "My Name");
sessionManader.BeginSession(companyFile, ENOpenMode.omDontCare);

IMsgSetRequest msgSetRq = qbSessionManager.CreateMsgSetRequest("CA", 7, 0);

IVendorMod vndrMod = msgSetRq.AppendVendorModRq();
vndrMod.CompanyName.SetValue("TEST COMPANY");

//TODO ADD A FILTER ON ListID

IMsgSetResponse responseSet = sessionManager.DoRequests(msgSetRq);
```

My initial reaction is to try a Filter similar to this:

```
vndrQry.ORVendorListQuery.VendorListFilter.ActiveStatus.SetValue(ENActiveStatus.asActiveOnly);
```

That however does not appear to the way to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

```
vndrMod.ListID.SetValue("<ListID>");
vndrMod.EditSequence.SetValue("<EditSeq>");
```

Edit Sequence must be valid (ie from) from quickbooks.
And list id is immutable this is not a change value field.